# How to use raw2tiff function of libtiff library

Tags: c, tiff, cmyk, libtiff, raw-data

I am using libtiff library and found [this raw2tiff](http://www.libtiff.org/man/raw2tiff.1.html) that creates a tiff file from raw byte sequence. Other than the basic information found here, I could not find any additional information about how to use this function.

Specifically, I am trying to figure out how the raw data should be formatted. If anyone can explain how to use this function, or provide a reference that addresses this, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: When googling "libtiff documentation" you should find something relevant.

Comment: Yes, like I said in the original post, I have found the relevant documentation, which I did not find sufficient enough to understand how to use. So I am asking for more detailed information and/or the example of using the function.

Comment: The doc you link seems to be fairly thorough.  The command transforms raw raster data to TIFF format, with details of the input data format either specified via command-line options or guessed.  It is not so much a question of how the raw data should be formatted, but rather of how to get the program to correctly handle the data you have.  Perusing the options should give you an idea of what the program can handle.

Comment: There's probably a function called raw2tiff documented somewhere on the web. it may not be the same as yours. However writing a TIFF file, as opposed to reading one, is quite easy. Just look up the format, write a small header, and write out your pixel data.

Comment: I have CMYKraster data and need to export into tiff file. I am computing simple conversion from CMYKto RGB, but the file size is ridiculously huge for some reason. So while googling for a solution, I found about the raw2tiff and thought this raw2tiff function was already implemented in the libtiff library. Looks like it isn't a standard function of the libtiff library?